# interfacing python 2.7.12 with matlab 2017a

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to run some matlab image processing codes in python.  for interfacing matlab 2017a with python 2.7.12. i am getting an error stating that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    import matlab.engine
ImportError: No module named matlab.engine
```

I am new to python and also to coding.  please someone tell me how to proceed with the integration.

Comment: I don't know python but this error `ImportError: No module named matlab.engine` means it can't call or connect to Matlab. you need to install Matlab. your question is answered, please look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141631/running-matlab-using-python-gives-no-module-named-matlab-engine-error)

Comment: do i need to add my python to the same folder of my matlab?