# Running matlab codes in python

Tags: python, matlab

I am following this link to run matlab code in python: [Running Matlab using Python gives 'No module named matlab.engine' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141631/running-matlab-using-python-gives-no-module-named-matlab-engine-error)

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matlab\engine\matlabengine.py", line 71, in __call___stderr, feval=True).result()
File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matlab\engine\futureresult.py", line 67, in result
return self.__future.result(timeout)
File "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matlab\engine\fevalfuture.py", line 82, in result
self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None,out=self._out, err=self._err)

matlab.engine.EngineError: MATLAB function cannot be evaluated
```

I am using Python 3.6 windows 7, 64 bit
Matlab R2018b version

I have just written a simple function in matlab and saved the file as demo.m
The code is here:

```
 printk();
 function printk()
     fprintf(' Hello world!');
 end
```

and saved the file as demo.mat

Python idle:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.demo(nargout=0)
```

Can anyone please help. I need to migrate whole bunch of codes in python. Any other possible way would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the instructions on how to install the Python package? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: Does it only happen with `fprintf`?  have you tried some other function that does not use MATLAB's I/O features? Perhaps you cannot write in command line using MATLAB fucntions in python

Comment: Yes I installed in the same way as mentioned in the link At a macOS or Linux operating system prompt —

cd "matlabroot/extern/engines/python"
python setup.py install     Instead I used windows.

Comment: I need to check if it happens only with fprintf. Is there any alternative for it?

Comment: you say you saved it as a .mat file? .mat files are for matlab data. You should save it as a .m file. Apart from this I'm not sure if fprintf would work the way you want it to. I have no experience with the python engine but i know that with the c engine the print commands don't do anything. These output to the matlab command window and not to your python command window. If you want to print out something i think you're better off returning them to python and printing them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 64 bit python, if you have 64 bit matlab.

Maybe you are looking for something like:
https://github.com/Wilhox/Matlab-Shell-for-python.git