# Can't import matlab.engine in Matlab

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab

I installed the `matlab` module for python using [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) tutorial. Now I'm trying to import `matlab.engine` module in a .py file that's going to be executed inside Matlab. Here is the process and files:

My test.py file:

```
# test.py
import matlab.engine
```

On Matlab, I do:

```
>> mod = py.importlib.import_module('test');
>> py.reload(mod)
```

Error msg:

```
Error using test><module> (line 1) 
Python Error: ImportError: No module named engine
```

In my python file, even inside Matlab, when I just import `matlab` module, it works, but when I try to import `engine`, it fails...

**How can I import `matlab.engine` module inside Matlab?**

Obs.:

Module `matlab` imported inside Matlab:

```
>> py.importlib.import_module('matlab')
ans = 
  Python module with properties:
    Buffer: [1×1 py.type]
    <module 'libmwbuffer' from 'C:\MATLAB\R2018b\bin\win64\libmwbuffer.pyd'>
```

Module `matlab` imported outside Matlab (cmd.exe, for instance):

```
>>> import matlab
>>> matlab
<module 'matlab' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matlab\__init__.pyc'>
```

Look at the paths. **Is it a conflict?**

The `import matlab.engine` works outside Matlab, if I run in the cmd.exe, for example, it works.

Using Matlab 2018b, Python 2.7. Everything x64. Windows 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141631/running-matlab-using-python-gives-no-module-named-matlab-engine-error This should solve your problem, check it out

Comment: I already made this. `import matlab` works. And `import matlab.engine` works outside Matlab. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: So you want to run a MATLAB session inside a Python session that is running inside a MATLAB session? That makes no sense. And I’m not surprised they don’t let you do that.

Comment: I could be running another matlab process. So it would not be a problem. I believe...

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve by running MATLAB inside Python inside MATLAB? There is likely a better solution to it.

Comment: Yes. There are better solutions, but to solve an specific problem for a specific situation here, I would need to use this.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a better way to solve your specific problem in your specific situation. I think you're stuck in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want help, describe your specific problem in your specific situation, not the solution you think is the one you need.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, there are two ways to run a algorithm here. One in C++ and another in Matlab. Is important to have these two possibilities. The problem is to keep this algorithm the same for both platforms. Then, to solve this problem, without changing the way people call this algorithm in both ways, was to move the core of this algorithm to python and both matlab and C++ would call it.

Comment: Ok, but if you have an algorithm in Python, why does that algorithm need to call MATLAB? You need MATLAB calling your Python algorithm, but you are trying to get MATLAB to call a MATLAB algorithm through Python, and that makes no sense.

Comment: An easier solution is to implement the algorithm in C++ and build a MEX-file so it’s usable from MATLAB.

Comment: I need MATLAB to call the algorithm to don't change how people call the algorithm today. I need Python to call matlab, because It will need to interact with a simulink model. But the Python will also need to interact with a C++ model. A mex file will not solve, because the people who really writes algorith don't know C++.

Comment: I think I will call python with `system`, the connect to the same Matlab session, but I'll have to see what would be blocking or not...